# Create a directed weighted graph using python-igraph and mysql results

Tags: python, mysql, igraph

I am using python-igraph and trying to generate a directed weighted graph from a MySQL query results. I run a query on a table in my dataset and I want to create the graph based on that. Basically my query will return the following:

```
A B Weight
1 2 3
2 4 5
```

Can anyone explain how it can be done using python-igraph? Is it possible at all?

Comment: You can use the `ncol` format. Note that it will use symbolic names, which will probably remap your node ids. http://igraph.org/python/doc/igraph.GraphBase-class.html#Read_Ncol

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming that you are querying the database directly from Python using an appropriate DB-API 2.0 compatible MySQL module, you can use the `Graph.DictList` method to achieve your goal. [`Graph.DictList`](http://igraph.org/python/doc/igraph.Graph-class.html#DictList) creates a graph from a list-of-dictionaries representation, and it is possible to configure the MySQL query cursor to yield dictionaries instead of tuples when you fetch a row. This is untested since I don't have a MySQL database at hand, but it shows the general idea:

```
import MySQLdb
import MySQLdb.cursors

conn = MySQLdb.connect(host='...', cursorclass=MySQLdb.cursors.DictCursor)

cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.execute("SELECT source, target, weight FROM whatever")
graph = Graph.DictList(vertices=None, edges=cursor, edge_foreign_keys=('source', target'))
```

The important part here is to use `cursorclass=MySQLdb.cursors.DictCursor` when you connect to the database. The code snippet above also makes use of the fact that `cursor` is iterable so it might not work with other database modules, but it is easy to take a generic DB-API 2.0 cursor and make it iterable by just using `iter(cursor.fetchone, None)`.

Also, make sure that the two column names you pass in `edge_foreign_keys` matches the names of the columns in the MySQL query that contain the source and target nodes. Any other column in the query result will be saved as edge attributes.

Comment: Just to mention that if using psycopg2 package to connect PostgreSQL, use conn.cursor(cursor_factory = psycopg2.extras.RealDictCursor) to generate dictionaries representation.

Comment: +1 for just bringing up the DictList function in iGraph. I was searching through the docs for a way to read in an edgelist from memory all day! Ended up using TupleList.

Comment: You mentioned in your answer that you couldn't verify this solution.  I did.  To use strings as keys, make sure your connection has the correct cursor type: cursorclass=MySQLdb.cursors.DictCursor